# Why doesn't my GUI appear when running from powershell.exe -file?

Tags: wpf, powershell, runspace

I am writing a Powershell script utilizing WPF with the methods shown here: http://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/.

My script runs perfectly when I execute it from the within Powershell comand line as ".\Test.ps1."  If I attempt to launch the same script from, for instance, a batch file like so:

```
powershell.exe -file D:\Test.ps1
```

Powershell launches and shortly exits thereafter, without displaying the GUI.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the runspaces but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try running it like this: `powershell.exe -sta -file D:\Test.ps1`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's experencing the same issue

Comment: Might need to add -NoExit in order for this to work properly `powershell.exe -NoExit -sta -file D:\Test.ps1`